# How do I make a day come first while using the dateStyle in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, nsdate, dateformatter

I want to make the day come first instead of the month while using the *dateStyle* feature of *DateFormatter()*. I tried all possible ways I know but nothing seems to work.
Here is my code.

```
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()           
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
        print(dateFormatter.string(from: beginDate))  //05 Jul 2020          
        dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true           
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium            
        print(dateFormatter.string(from: beginDate)) //Jul 5, 2020
```

I want the last line to print "5 Jul, 2020". The *dateStyle* is important becuase without that the `dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting` will not work. There should be a simple way to do it. Please Help.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that people from different parts of the world prefer different formats? Chinese and Japanese for example, goes year, month, day. Would you still want the day first if the user was Chinese?

Comment: you should not use dateFormat and dateStyle together. It is one or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to change anything in your code. Just switch your Simulator's Region (Settings -> General -> Language & Region) to a place that uses the little endian (day, month, year) style ([here's a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)). A typical example is the UK.

If you want to *always* show the day first, regardless of the user's region, you can set the `locale` of the date formatter to one of those countries listed above:

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-GB")
```

But I don't recommend this. You should not disrespect the user's language and region and their preferred date format unless you have a really good reason.

Answer (score 1):

The string that is printed on the last command respects the locale of the user.

To do what you want, you can force it using

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: <identifier>)
```

To check a list of all the formats, you can do

```
Locale.availableIdentifiers.sorted().forEach { identifier in
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: identifier)
    dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium

    print("identifier: \(identifier) - \(dateFormatter.string(from: beginDate))")
}
```